# DateTime Picker in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying with the following code to use datetime picker and i want the date format to be **dd/MM/yyyy**

```
$(".datepick").datepicker({
            dateFormat:'dd-MM-yyyy'               
        });
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The full year is **yy** not **yyyy**

So use

```
$(".datepick").datepicker({
    dateFormat:'dd-MM-yy'               
});
```

You can see the available date formats at http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/MhQaf/